# Android AdMob and Maven

Tags: android, maven, admob

I have an Android Project where I need to build multiple versions of the same application from the same sources.

To do this, I use the [android plugin for Maven](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/)

Each version must be able to include ads from admob. So in my POM I added this dependancy

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.admob.android</groupId>
   <artifactId>ads</artifactId>
   <version>20101109-ANDROID-3312276cc1406347</version>
   <scope>system</scope>
   <systemPath>THE_PATH\libs\admob-sdk-android.jar</systemPath>
 </dependency>
```

I don't get any errors at build time but, when I execute the application I get this exception

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.admob.android.ads.AdView
```

So apparently the package is not properly included ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can NOT use system scope for runtime required libraries. Deploy the jar into your local repository or your repository server (using e.g. [mvn install:installFile](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html) ..) and remove scope and systemPath from the dependency declaration.

**Update:** As of the latest releases my [Maven Android SDK Deployer](https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer) can do the install of the AdMob jar from the SDK into your local Maven repository or repository server for you.

Answer (score 1):

To use the Maven Android SDK Deployer, do the following:

- Clone the repo:

  git clone https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer.git
- Go to your SDK Manager and install all APIs (this may take a while if you haven't done it yet)
- Make sure you have the correct environment variable set for ANDROID_HOME. For Windows this might be:

  set ANDROID_HOME=c:/android-sdk-windows
- Run the installer:

  c:\Tools\maven-android-sdk-deployer>mvn install

After you have done this you can just use all the android dependencies from your pom.xml, e.g.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android.admob</groupId>
        <artifactId>admob</artifactId>
        <version>6.4.1-r11</version>
    </dependency>
```

(There's a whole list on the github page)