# How to integrate admob to Dukescript generated apk?

Tags: android, admob, dukescript

How do you add **AdMob** advertising functionality to your dukescript generated **android** project?

Let's say for example that I addeded android to the [Hello World example](https://github.com/GeertjanWielenga/DukeScriptSamples/tree/master/KnockoutLiveExamples/01-HelloWorld/HelloWorld) and that the app is already published so I can add some `ad unit`s trough admob site, for example Ad unit ID `ca-app-pub-99999999999999999/9999999999` for an interstitial and Ad unit ID `ca-app-pub-9999999999999999/9999999998` for banner.

As far as I know you can't show them with javascript only, you should add some jars to the libraries folders and call explicitly some of their functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the required libraries. There's a related question how to install them to your local repository [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960954/android-admob-and-maven).

After you installed the libraries and reference them in your android project, you should be able to use AdMob. Follow the description here to [wrap the DukeScript MainActivity](https://dukescript.com/best/practices/2015/11/20/AndroidBoot.html) in your own MainActivity. Then you should be able to create ads in the onCreate method [as described here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/existing-app).

```
    import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

public class AndroidMain extends Activity {

    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this.getApplicationContext());
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("pub-99999999999999999/9999999999");
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice("adb logcat will show you the id")
                .build();
        // Prepare an Interstitial Ad Listener
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                displayInterstitial();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        com.dukescript.presenters.Android.class));
                finish();
            }

        });
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    public void displayInterstitial() {
        // If Ads are loaded, show Interstitial else show nothing.
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "The asd has not Loaded.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        Main.onPageLoad();
    }
}
```

If you've finished that, modify your pom.xml to include not only the jar, but also the apklib of google play services:

```
    <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-play-services</artifactId>
    <version>28.0.0</version>
    <type>apklib</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-play-services</artifactId>
    <version>28.0.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

You wil also need to modify your AndroidManifest.xml and add some permissions and an activity. Here's the code for your app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="web.aprendiendola.dictionaryweb.aprendiendola.dictionary.DiccionarioDeJava"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0-SNAPSHOT" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="DiccionarioDeJava"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <activity android:name="web.aprendiendola.dictionaryweb.aprendiendola.dictionary.DiccionarioDeJava.AndroidMain" 
                  android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.dukescript.presenters.Android" 
                  android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
                  android:exported="false"
        >
        </activity>
         <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

        <!-- Configuration section. Defines: 
           - the HTML page to load on start
           - the class that contains the main initialization method
           - name of the initialization method in the given class
        -->
        <meta-data android:name="loadPage" android:value="file:///android_asset/pages/index.html" />
        <meta-data android:name="loadClass" android:value="web.aprendiendola.dictionaryweb.aprendiendola.dictionary.DiccionarioDeJava.AndroidMain" />
        <meta-data android:name="invoke" android:value="main" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />        
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
</manifest>
```

That's it, you should now be able to display an ad. It works for me with the application you sent me.

Comment: Thank you So mucho Mr. Epple It worked like a charm!